# Mapping products and shopping cart - NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I was trying my hands on NHibernate and Fluent NHiberate. I wrote two classes as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingCart
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public decimal CartTotal
    {
        get { return Products.Aggregate(0m, (c,x)=>  c + x.Price; ); }
    }

    public ShoppingCart()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

I want to map `Product` and `ShoppingCart` but I don't want any `ShoppingCart.Id` as key in `Products` table. How can I define map using `Fluent NHibernate`?

PS:- I have tried mapping `Category` and `SucCategory` using self-referencing category. But I am not able to wrap my head around `ShoppingCart` and `Product` problem. Also I want to use `MS Sql Server CE 4.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you want a many-to-many relationship. This can be done in Fluent with a mapping like this:

```
public class ShoppingCartMap : ClassMap<ShoppingCart>
{
    public ShoppingCartMap()
    {
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Products).Table("ShoppingCartToProduct");
        // Other properties follow...
    }
}
```

This will generate a table named "ShoppingCartToProduct" with two foreign key columns (one to Product.Id and one to ShoppingCart.Id).